# Se puede agregar categorías a una búsqueda mediante botones

Tags: php, html

me preguntaba si puedo agregar categorías a mi búsqueda mediante botones, que solo lo piques y al darle buscar te lo busque con la categoría que tú has escogido. 
Se podría decir que tengo el botón que vais a ver mas abajo, puedo hacer que eso me funcione conjuntamente con la búsqueda que yo hago.
La categoría son los precios.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btn-group ">
  <a style="margin-left:60px" class="btn btn-success" href="#">Price</a>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="BORDER: rgb(130,128,130) 0,5px solid; FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR:LightGreen; rgb(233,233,233)">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1$-5$</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5$-10$</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10$-15$</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">+15$</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: puedes agregar más información adjunta, como el código PHP. Y tu formulario de búsqueda. Para así dar una idea más concisa del problema. Gracias

Comment: Se podría hacer muy fácilmente por medio de Ajax. En el cliente escuchas el botón que se haya clickeado, recoges la categoría del mismo y la mandas al servidor para que haga la consulta en base a esa categoría. Es un uso básico de HTML-Javascript-Ajax / PHP.